# Javascript - Set Object null if all its properties are null

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an object like this:

```
var user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: null,
        address: {
            line1: null,
            line2: null,
            city: null,
            state: null
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to iterate the properties and check if its properties are null. If they are all null I want to set that property null. This means starting from address whose values are all null so set address = null, then name and address are both null so personalInfo should be set null etc...

So my Object ends ups like this:

```
var user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: null
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where you will see that we ask you to research your issue and make an attempt at a solution and to post that attempt in your question. We're happy to answer specific questions, but we're not a code writing service. Your solution will rely on recursive looping so you should start by researching that and come on back with any specific questions about the code you are attempting.

Comment: To be honest I made some attempts and couldn't make it work with recursion. Thats why I asked... I don't want to be embarrased :P

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed about! You can always edit your question and include the attempt(s) you've made. Any code that runs (not necessarily correctly) should be included in a "code snippet" (the `{}` button on your question toolbar) so that we can easily run it and also easily copy it into any answers we may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate all key/value pairs and decrement a count for all `null` values for this level. If all values are `null`, return `null`, otherwise the changed object.

For checking the nested objects, take the value and the type and call the function again and assign the result to the key.

```js
function setNull(object) {
    var entries = Object.entries(object),
        count = entries.length;
    
    entries.forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (null === (v && typeof v === 'object' && (object[k] = setNull(v)))) {
            count--;
        }
    });

    return count
        ? object
        : null;
}

var user = { id: 101, email: 'jack@dev.com', personalInfo: { name: null, address: { line1: null, line2: null, city: null, state: null } } };

console.log(setNull(user));
```

Comment: Here is a single line version for people who are crazy. `const setNull = obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => [k, v && typeof v === 'object' ? setNull(v) : v]).filter(([k,v]) => v !== null).reduce((acc,cur) => {acc = acc ? acc : {}; acc[cur[0]] = cur[1]; return acc;}, null);` It will map across the key value object entries recurse any values that are objects, remove nulls, and produce a null or object. This isn't a better solution, just presents you with alternative methods you may not have considered.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this recursively like so:

```
function isAllNull(obj) {                               // this function checks if an object contain only null values, i.e. checks if it is a null object or not
    for(var key in obj) {                               
        if(obj[key] !== null) {                         // if there is at least one property that is not null
            return false;                               // then the object doesn't qualify
        }
    }
    return true;                                        // otherwise if all properties are null
}

function nullify(obj) {                                 // this function takes an object and replace all its null child objects with null
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {  // if the current value is an object
            nullify(obj[key]);                          // nullfiy it first (turn its null children objects to null)
            if(isAllNull(obj[key])) {                   // then check if it is a null object
                obj[key] = null;                        // if so replace it with null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function isAllNull(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] !== null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function nullify(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            nullify(obj[key]);
            if(isAllNull(obj[key])) {
                obj[key] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

var user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: null,
        address: {
            line1: null,
            line2: null,
            city: null,
            state: null
        }
    }
};

nullify(user);

console.log(user);
```

Comment: :( If we just provide working solutions to questions that simply request them, don't you think that will encourage more of the same?

Comment: Because SO has guidelines for [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the site is not intended to be a place to come to place "orders" for code to be written. It is expected that users will do their research and make an attempt at a solution first.

Comment: Your answer, for example, relies on knowledge of `for/in`, `if/then`, indexes/keys, and return values. How do you know that the OP has any knowledge of any of those things? Your answer could lead to lengthy conversations about fundamental aspects of the code that have no direct bearing on the original question.

Comment: I did searched things like "how to iterate in object properties" etc, i just couldn't make it work all together because I find recursion kinda hard :D. Thanks for the answer @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @ScottMarcus While I totally agree with the guidelines, I sometimes find it better to just bend them a little bit. For example, if the question is really good (clean and straightforward) and doesn't have a homework vibe to it and also can be very useful in the future for other people, then I just go ahead and answer it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function by passing a object and it will return object as you need,

```
function setNulls(obj) {
    var flag = false;
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] != null && typeof obj[key] == "object") {
            obj[key] = setNulls(obj[key]);
        }
        if (obj[key] != null) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag)
        return obj;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works, because It was one of my attempts and It didn't work for me.

Comment: When I was trying to do something like this I had written `setNulls(obj[key]);` instead of `obj[key] = setNulls(obj[key]);` for some reason. Thanks for helping me understand my mistake !

Comment: It's a recursive function call, So basically something has to be updated or changed, If nothing is assigned to the return value of function call that doesn't make any sense because at beginning of the first function call it returns an object so when making recursive call its returned value should be used somehow.