# Set Object null if all its properties are null in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to write a function which it turns every properies and child properties of an object. And if all properties of one property are null, then I will set that property as null. I will explain with one example.

For example, if both `TeacherName` and `TeacherSurname` are null then I want to set `Teacher` to null. Then, if `ExamMark` and `ExamName` and `Teacher` are null, then `Exam` will be null.

You can see json version of like my question from this link [Json Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990488/javascript-set-object-null-if-all-its-properties-are-null)

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }
}

public class Exam
{
    public string ExamMark { get; set; }
    public string ExamName { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherSurname { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

}
```

**I wrote this method. But this doing only first step. But I need recursive for child class. How can I convert this method to recursive?**

```
public static object ConvertToNull(object obj)
{
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();

    var mainClassProperties = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly);

    foreach (var mainClassProperty in mainClassProperties)
    {
       object propValue = mainClassProperty.GetValue(obj, null);
       var classAllProperties = propValue.GetType().GetProperties();

       if (propValue.GetType().GetProperties().All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(propValue) == null))
       {
           mainClassProperty.SetValue(obj, null);
       }
   }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: This really isn't a great design. Can you give some more background on how these objects are being created and why they are allowed to be created in invalid states?

Comment: My class is only example for telling my story. In my real scenario, one object coming from External Web Service with 300 property. But, a lot of child values are null like my question. So, I want to convert it to basic object. @KirkLarkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this The GetValueOrNull should work and do what you need, not tested with all possible use cases but it oculd be tweaked a little if doesn't work in all cases

```
public static bool IsSimpleType(Type type)
{
    return
        type.IsPrimitive ||
        new Type[] {
    typeof(Enum),
    typeof(String),
    typeof(Decimal),
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(DateTimeOffset),
    typeof(TimeSpan),
    typeof(Guid)
        }.Contains(type) ||
        Convert.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object ||
        (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) && IsSimpleType(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        ;
}
public object GetValueOrNull(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return null;
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    var simpleTypes = properties.Where(t => IsSimpleType(t.PropertyType));

    var nonValueTypes = properties.Where(p => !simpleTypes.Contains(p));
    foreach (var child in nonValueTypes)
    {
        child.SetValue(obj, GetValueOrNull(child.GetValue(obj)));
    }
    return simpleTypes.All(z => z.GetValue(obj) == null) && nonValueTypes.All(z => z.GetValue(obj) == null) ? null : obj;
}
```

call it as follows

```
var student = new Student { Address = new Address { }, Exam = new Exam { Teacher = new Teacher() } };
            var test = GetValueOrNull(student);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: But, if you change part of your code `var simpleTypes = properties.Where(t => IsSimpleType(t.PropertyType)); var nonValueTypes = properties.Where(p => !simpleTypes.Contains(p));` to this code `var simpleTypes = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Assembly != objType.Assembly);   var nonValueTypes = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly);`  ,then you can delete `IsSimpleType` method . Because you won't need that method.   Can you edit your answer please, if I'm right? @user5195490

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution worked perfectly. But `UmairAnwaar`'s solution is shorter. So, I marked as an answer. @npo

Comment: @HasanOzdemir Yes, looks shorter, the only thing missing is the Function to check if its primitive value. But i don't think that will work alwasy, what happens to classes that are not part of your assembly lets they come from some nuget package and you use some model inside of your class. That wouldn't be the same assembly as the parent object would it?

Comment: Thanks again. Yes. In that situation, `UmairAnwaar`'s answer will run incorrectly. I think, it will be more correct that I mark this answer as correct answer. @npo

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is actually an anti-pattern. What this does is it propagates the requirement for tons of null checks in your code. Not only do you have to check if all properties are null, you also have to check if your object is null when you want to use it. Also reflection is very slow and if you're doing this often, you'll bog down your application.

You should look into the [Null Object Pattern](https://deviq.com/null-object-pattern/). It basically does what you want it to, and you remove all those pesky null checks:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public static Student NullStudent { get; } = new Student
    {
        Name = null,
        Surname = null,
        Address = Address.NullAddress,
        Exam = Exam.NullExam,
    }
}
```

You can do this for each object in your code that acts this way (you can see that I did it on your nested Address and Exam types as well) and then instead of doing this:

```cs
if (Student.EverythingIsNull) { Student = null }
if (Student is null) { //do null stuff }
```

You can do this:

```cs
if (item == Student.NullStudent) { //do null stuff }
```

This leads to clearer code, your intent stands out more, and you can specifically define in each object what constitutes as null.

Comment: Thanks. But, in your solution, the object created by you. But in my situation, object doesn't created by me. Because object comes from External Web Service.

Comment: In the sample provided, `item` is the item that comes in from the web service, and `Student.NullStudent` is created by you to compare against. Basically, you build a "known null state" of the object, and then compare the incoming object to it.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir `Student.NullStudent` isn't the object created by your web service. It's a comparable object that you define. What you're basically saying is "Here's what a null version of this object looks like. If the object i get from my web service has all of the values of `NullStudent` (in this case all null values), then it is essentially null." If by "I'm not creating the object" you mean "This class is in a separate source code that I can't touch" then you can just define`NullStudent` as a static member somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your answer after your comment now @TheHeadmaster . But this is impossible for my real scenario. Because in my scenario, there will be more than 300 properties. And a lot of child of child of child of.... And this is only for one example. There will be 20 class like this. So, this means, thousands of code rows. `user5195490`'s answer what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir I understand, happy to have helped. If thats your real world scenario then it sounds like a nightmare, the objects sound like they are doing way too much. If you do have any influence over making changes to that in your company i'd urge you to do so. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

using Generics and Reflection.

```
    public T ConvertToNull<T>(T model) where T : class
    {
        if (model == null) return null;
        Type type = model.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties =  type.GetProperties();

        var valueTypes = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Assembly != type.Assembly);
        var nonValueTypes = properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType.Assembly == type.Assembly);

        foreach (var nonValueType in nonValueTypes)
            nonValueType.SetValue(model, ConvertToNull(nonValueType.GetValue(model)));

        if (valueTypes.All(z => z.GetValue(model) == null) && nonValueTypes.All(z => z.GetValue(model) == null))
            return null;
        else
            return model;
    }
```

Here you can call it

```
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        Student student = new Student() { Name = "StudentName", Surname = "StudentSurname", Address = new Address() { City = "City", Country = "Country" }, Exam = new Exam() { ExamMark = "ExamMark", ExamName = "ExamName", Teacher = new Teacher() { TeacherName = "TeacherName", TeacherSurname = "TeacherSurname" } } };

        Student student2 = new Student() { Name = "StudentName", Surname = "StudentSurname", Address = new Address(), Exam = new Exam() { ExamMark = "ExamMark", ExamName = "ExamName", Teacher = new Teacher() } };

        students.Add(student);
        students.Add(student2);

        List<Student> results = new List<Student>();
        foreach (var item in students)
        {
            var result = ConvertToNull(item);
            results.Add(result);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @UmairAnwaar. Both `npo`' s answer and your answer worked perfectly.